# HTML, Thymeleaf - displaying an image conditionally

Tags: html, thymeleaf

My task is to display a rating with stars.

I want to display a half star if the rating does not end with a zero.

The attribute 'odd' contains a zero if the number ends with a zero .

I need help with the 'if' statement.

```
<tr th:each="comp : ${companies}">

    <td">
        <img th:src="@{/images/star.png}"
             th:each="star:${#numbers.sequence(1, comp.avgRating)}">

        <img th:src="@{/images/halfstar.png}"     

    th:if="${comp.odd &gt; 0}" ? th:each="halfstar:${#numbers.sequence(0, comp.odd)}"> 

    </td>
</tr>
```

Some ideas ?

Comment: th:if="${comp.odd > 0}" should work. But I would wrap <img> tag inside a <div> and put th:if condition to <div>

Comment: I'd rather compute in the controller how many half-stars should be shown. And you add that number to the model. And just show that number of stars.

Comment: @aepure or rather, compute it in the service layer and add that number to the model through the controller

Comment: @bphilipnyc it really depends how complex the computation is :) if it's a one-liner, adding a service for it would be over-engineering. anyhow, that's offtopic.

Comment: Not really - single responsibility principle