# How to show an image conditionally in Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I have a controller that returns a `ReponseEntity<byte[]>` image and I can show it with the following tag:

```
<img th:src="@{'./my-files/main-logo'}"
```

I can also show an image from the /img/ folder with this tag:

```
<img th:src="@{/img/default-logo.png}"
```

I want to show the image from the database when it is present, and the image from the folder as a default if the ResponseEntity is null.

I tried all kind of ternary conditions but none of them worked.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried adding the attribute `th:if="${...}"` in your `<img>`? (`...` being where you check if the image is null)

Comment: @TwiN To do this, I should add a variable to the model that says the image is null ? The controller I'm using is returning a ResponseEntity<byte[]> which is the image when it finds it or null otherwise. How could I check if a ResponseEntity<byte[]> is null ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the attribute `th:if="${...}"` in your `<img />` tag.

You can try to call the method which returns the image programatically (e.g. `nameOfTheImageController.getImage(...)`) and add a boolean to your model that represents whether the image is null or not.

Then, you can just add that boolean variable in the `<img>`'s `th:if`.

**UPDATE**

As mentioned in a comment in 
[HTML, Thymeleaf - displaying an image conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44189674/html-thymeleaf-displaying-an-image-conditionally), you should wrap your `<img>` tag inside a `<div>` and put the `th:if` attribute in the `<div>` tag instead.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, instead of changing the src of the image, you should change your `/my-files/main-logo` controller to return `img/default-logo.png` as a the `ResponseEntity<byte[]>` if there is no main-logo.  That way you can just leave your image tag as is:

```
<img th:src="@{'./my-files/main-logo'}" />
```

If you don't want to do that, then yes, you'll have to add something to your controller that tells you whether or not you have a main logo. Something like this for example:

```
<img th:if="${has_logo}" th:src="@{'./my-files/main-logo'}" />
<img th:unless="${has_logo}" th:src="@{/img/default-logo.png}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following syntax. in your controller add a model attribute hasImageInDatabase when response is null. then from thymeleaf use the below syntax.

```
<img th:src="${(hasImageInDatabase ?: '/my-files/main-logo': '/img/default-logo.png'}"/>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22723738)

Comment: Harsh Patel - please explain properly what you would like to point out and why you think this is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
<img th:src="./my-files/main-logo" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='/img/default-logo.png';">
```

It means if the first link to the photo didn't work `("./my-files/main-logo" )` or was `null`, it will show the second photo`('/img/default-logo.png')`.